# quarkus: blocked by CORS policy

Tags: java, cors, quarkus

although I configured the property file I still get the error:

```
blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

> I also created a **@Provider** extending **ContainerRequestFilter**, but it
>   never reaches there

application.properties

```
# Configuration file
quarkus.http.port=9090
quarkus.http.cors=true
quarkus.http.origins=http://localhost:4200, localhost:9090
quarkus.http.headers=accept, authorization, content-type, x-requested-with
quarkus.http.methods=GET, OPTIONS
```

**edited**

```
17:11:09 WARN  [io.qu.config]] (build-3) Unrecognized configuration key "quarkus.http.methods" provided
17:11:09 WARN  [io.qu.config]] (build-3) Unrecognized configuration key "quarkus.http.headers" provided
17:11:09 WARN  [io.qu.config]] (build-3) Unrecognized configuration key "quarkus.http.origins" provided
```

Comment: Hi it seems like some methods are missing in the http.methods what are method are you using GET/POST/PUT?

Comment: only GET for these services

Comment: Can you try adding a /* to your localhost:4200

Comment: also does not work, not even with on the * nor empty or without the config line

Answer (score 19):

The warnings were a good indication.

Your configuration is incorrect.

It should be something like:

```
quarkus.http.cors=true
quarkus.http.cors.origins=http://localhost:4200,http://localhost:9090
quarkus.http.cors.headers=accept, authorization, content-type, x-requested-with
quarkus.http.cors.methods=GET, OPTIONS
```

yaml config

```
quarkus:
  http:
    cors:
      ~: true
      origins: http://localhost:4200,http://localhost:9090
      headers: accept, authorization, content-type, x-requested-with
      methods: GET, OPTIONS, POST
```

with the `cors` prefix.

We don't have proper documentation right now so better refer to https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/master/extensions/undertow/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/undertow/runtime/filters/CORSConfig.java .

I opened https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/3156 to track the documentation issue.

Comment: Hi Guillaume, yep, in the g-groups/zulip they already told me, I correct them all and try again with the same result
I mean, no warnings anymore, but I cannot get into my resource from my angular app

Comment: Documentation about CORS filter can be found here https://quarkus.io/guides/http-reference#cors-filter

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code, this worked for me.

```
<code>
@Provider   
public class CorsFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {
  @Override
  public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
    responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    responseContext.getHeade`enter code here`rs().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
    responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
    responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "100000");
  }
}
</code>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Adding `origin` to the list of headers accepted, fixed my issue.

These were my config properties:

```
quarkus.http.cors.origins=/.*/
quarkus.http.cors.headers=origin, accept, authorization, content-type, x-requested-with
quarkus.http.cors.access-control-allow-credentials=true
quarkus.http.cors.methods=GET,PUT,POST
quarkus.tls.trust-all=true
```